# How to automatically let Google Reader send ping to hub on feed updates (PubSubHubBub)?

Tags: rss, websub

I am trying to receive real-time notifications from Google Reader whenever my rss-feed updates. To do so, I have created a public folder in the reader, and subscribed to its hub (pubsubhubbub.appspot.com). When the hub sends its verification ping to my callback (on my server), I return the hub.challenge and see on the subscription details page (pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscription-details) that it has been verified.

However, after this, nothing happens; whenever my feed updates, it does not seem like Google Reader pings the callback, so I do not receive any updates of my feed. But, when I "publicize" the topic via https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/publish, Google does send a ping, and my callback function does receive updates of the feed.

I would like Google Reader to automatically send the ping to the hub whenever the feed updates. How should I accomplish this? Reading the article on http://googlereader.blogspot.nl/2009/08/pubsubhubbub-support-for-reader-shared.html, this seems to be done automatically, but I really can't seem to get it to work?

Thank you all in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you describe it looks like Google Reader fails to ping its hub when the feed is updated... which means there is little you can do, except manually pinging the hub every time. That would break the purpose i guess.

Another solution is to look at http://superfeedr.com (which I created, sorry for the plug!), because we do poll feeds for which we have no way of detecting updates; So you'll get a ping at most 15 minutes after you published something new in your feed. Not perfect, but at least fully automated.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll definitely have a look at your site.